# Elasticsearch start failing after java upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch

I upgraded my Java version from java 6 to java 7 and restarted elasticsearch. But now its failing to start and i am not able to figure out why. The logs looks like this:

```
[2015-06-26 12:39:12,151][INFO ][node                     ] [D'Spayre] version[1.4.0], pid[17934], build[bc94bd8/2014-11-05T14:26:12Z]
[2015-06-26 12:39:12,152][INFO ][node                     ] [D'Spayre] initializing ...
[2015-06-26 12:39:12,157][ERROR][bootstrap                ] {1.4.0}: Initialization Failed ...
- NullPointerException[null]
```

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: And do you have the complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: @AndreiStefan: This is a default logs generated in the log file. Can I generate complete stack strace somehow?

Comment: Go to `logging.yml` file under `/config` and change `es.logger.level: INFO` to `es.logger.level: TRACE`. Try to start again ES. Post here or on pastebin.com the resulted log file.

Comment: @AndreiStefan: Found the issue, the permission to my plugin directory was somehow changes which caused this issue. Thanks

Comment: Cool ;-), I'm assuming the TRACE logging revealed something not visible before.

Comment: @AndreiStefan: Thanks. Yup it did.